# Providing more than one join criteria with the help of 'OR' conditional operator in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Please find the below provided query which I'm able to implement in Netezza where in case there is no join on 'id' then it looks for the join on the basis of 'name'. if any of the criteria gets fulfilled then Left outer join is performed.

```
Select * from BigqueryTest.colors a 
LEFT JOIN 
BigqueryTest.color2 b
ON a.id = b.id
OR a.name = b.name ;
```

This functionality doesn't seem to be supported in Bigquery. I mean to say that I can provide multiple joining conditions with the help of 'AND' operator but can't use 'OR' operator which can allow me moving ahead with Join operation even if a single condition gets satisfied out of many. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: not sure why it does not support `OR`, but you could split them into two part,and `union` them together

Comment: Apologies as I don't have much experience tweaking the SQL pieces. So could you please be more precise that how can I split this query based on the conditions separated by 'OR'.

Comment: `Select * from BigqueryTest.colors a 
LEFT JOIN 
BigqueryTest.color2 b
ON a.id = b.id UNION 
Select * from BigqueryTest.colors a 
LEFT JOIN 
BigqueryTest.color2 b ON a.name = b.name ;` but still do not know why you cannot use `OR`

Comment: The error message I get while using OR : Error: LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

Comment: I think this is a issue specific to `bigquery`, try to find similar question and the answers online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... is there any way around to make the code run with 'OR' condition? Because in actual scenario there are more than 100 columns ...

Below is another option - as a direction for you to explore.

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT a.id AS aid, a.name AS aname, b.id AS bid, b.name AS bname
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a, IF(matches = 0, STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>(NULL, NULL), b) AS b 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            a, b, 
            (a.id = b.id OR a.name = b.name) AS match, 
            COUNTIF(a.id = b.id OR a.name = b.name) 
              OVER(PARTITION BY a.id, a.name) AS matches,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id, a.name) AS dup
        FROM `BigqueryTest.colors` AS a
        CROSS JOIN `BigqueryTest.color2` AS b
    )
    WHERE match OR (matches = 0 AND dup = 1)
)
-- ORDER BY a.id
```

You can test/play with it using below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `BigqueryTest.colors` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'b' AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 'c' AS name 
),
`BigqueryTest.color2` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'a' AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT 11 AS id, 'a' AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'b' AS name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'x' AS name
)
SELECT a.id AS aid, a.name AS aname, b.id AS bid, b.name AS bname
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a, IF(matches = 0, STRUCT<id INT64, name STRING>(NULL, NULL), b) AS b 
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      a, b, 
      (a.id = b.id OR a.name = b.name) AS match, 
      COUNTIF(a.id = b.id OR a.name = b.name) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id, a.name) AS matches,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id, a.name) AS dup
    FROM `BigqueryTest.colors` AS a
    CROSS JOIN `BigqueryTest.color2` AS b
  )
  WHERE match OR (matches = 0 AND dup = 1)
)
ORDER BY a.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  a.id AS aid, a.name AS aname, 
  b.id AS bid, b.name AS bname
FROM `BigqueryTest.colors` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `BigqueryTest.color2` AS b
ON a.id = b.id 
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT 
  a.id AS aid, a.name AS aname, 
  b.id AS bid, b.name AS bname
FROM `BigqueryTest.colors` AS a 
LEFT JOIN `BigqueryTest.color2` AS b
ON a.name = b.name
```

Comment: Thank you !!! It works but is there any way around to make the code run with 'OR' condition.Because in actual scenario there are more than 100 columns and lots of other Join conditions, so splitting them and then using 'Union' doesn't seem to be a standard solution.However, highly appreciate for this workaround.

Comment: Using `OR` with `JOIN` doesn't scale very well because BigQuery can't hash partition the table (in order to parallelize the computation) on any particular key. Alternatively, you can use `CROSS JOIN` with an arbitrary condition.